# Skip (or not supplying an optional parameters)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sp-executesql

How do I skip (or not supply an optional parameters) with `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`?

```
create procedure SetElementFrequency
  @ElementTypeID integer,
  @Frequency float = null,
  @ElementName integer,
as ...
```

I tried the following without any luck..  it still expects for me to supply the `@Frequency` param

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "exec SetElementFrequency {0}, {1}",
    elementType, elementName);
```

and

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "exec SetElementFrequency @ElementTypeID, @ElementName",
    elementType, elementName);
```

**EDIT:**

The "@Frequency" param will be completely removed from the stored procedure in the future. There are some legacy applications still supplying for `@Frequency` and it is not an option to change it in all applications. Newly created applications will not be supplying the `@Frequency`

Answer (score 1):

You could change your exec format to use the SQL parametrisation like this and see if it works better for you:

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
"exec SetElementFrequency @ElementTypeID = {0}, @Frequency = {1}, @ElementName = {2}",
elementType, null, elementName);
```

Comment: ok... maybe i should be more clear.. the "@Frequency" param will be completely removed from the store proc in future..  There are some legacy applications still supplying for "@Frequency" and it is not an option to change it in all applications.   Newly created applications will not be supplying the @Frequency.